# Java - Maximum number of type parameters

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter

I recently read that type parameter names must be exactly one uppercase letter.

If this is the case, then wouldn't there be a maximum number of type parameters?

Would said maximum be equal to the number of uppercase letters that are also valid Java identifiers?

Comment: "I recently read that type parameter names must be exactly one uppercase letter." - That is incorrect. It's a convention, but not a requirement. A type parameter can be any valid identifier name, it does not need to be a single upper-case letter.

Comment: You read wrong.  Type parameters can be any identifier.  By convention, they are usually one uppercase letter, but I've also seen one uppercase letter followed by one digit, and I may have seen two or three uppercase letters.  Java doesn't care, though.  But if you don't follow the convention, you'll confuse people who try to read your code.

Comment: I don't know whether Java has a limit on the number of type parameters.  But your readers' sanity assuredly puts a limit on this.  I'd guess that the limit is 10 or less.  I believe the Java stream runtime has some cases with 5.

Comment: @ajb:  According to the JLS, "no".  Examples in languages like Clojure list type parameters going 26 types deep.

Comment: @Makoto I haven't even seen the Clojure code and my head already hurts.

Comment: @ajb:  Looking at the Clojure code won't make your head "hurt".  The code will be rough enough that, if you're fortunate, it'll just explode on sight.  They do some...interesting...things with their spread and map operations.

Comment: Where did you read this?

Comment: [How Many Type Parameters Can a Java Method Have?](https://justinblank.com/experiments/howmanytypeparameterscanajavamethodhave.html) by Justin Blank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *convention* is to use one letter for a type.  However, a type parameter is bound [only by the hard limits of an identifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2), which is to say, it has to be a valid Java identifier.  Any hard limits would *only* come from that.

There *are* valid cases in which it's acceptable to break the convention.  Specifically, back in the days of Java 7, if you were doing some kind of transformation which required two disjoint types, you could specify it as thus:

```
public <DatabaseDataFmt extends DatabaseDTO,
        ProjectionFmt extends ProjectionDTO,
        Result>
  Result transform(DatabaseDataFmt databaseFormat,
                   ProjectionFmt projectionFormat) {}
```

Ultimately it depends on what you want to accomplish with your identifiers.  Convention *helps*, but if it doesn't *help*, then there's no reason to be bound by it.